# How to pass argument into def_delegator

Tags: ruby, delegates, metaprogramming

In order to return the correct roster for a store, I need to be able to pass the store_id argument into the delegator. Is this possible?

```
require "forwardable"

class Store
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegator :@roster, :names, :roster

  attr_accessor :store_id

  def initialize(store_id)
    @store_id = store_id
    @roster = Roster.new
  end
end

class Roster
  def names(store_id)
    {
      1 => ['Ned', 'Smith', 'Jerry', 'Ben'],
      2 => ['Preeti', 'Jean', 'Sam', 'Lol']
    }[store_id]
  end
end

store = Store.new(1)
store.roster # => ['Ned', 'Smith', 'Jerry', 'Ben']
```

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't really delegation, and so Forwardable isn't a good fit. The simplest solution is to just define a method: `def roster; @roster.names(@store_id); end`